# Spring MVC - using a property file as sort of lookup table for Country field

Tags: spring-mvc

In my property file, I would have the ff.

```
country.1=Afghanistan
country.2=Albania
country.3=Algeria
country.4=Andorra
country.5=Angola
```

and, I'd like to have something like this in my view,

```
Country: <form:select path="customer">
    <form:options items="${countries}" />
</form:select>
```

which will then produce the following html.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Albania</option>
    <option value="3">Algeria</option>
    <option value="4">Andorra</option>
    <option value="5">Angola</option>
</select>
```

Do you have some suggestions on how to achieve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Use one property, delimited by something like `|` or maybe `::` or even `;`, then simply parse them out when the application loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a single property that had your list of countres:

countries=Afghanistan,Albania,...

You can get access to your properties file in you view controller by annotating the class with @PropertySource("classpath:countires.properties") and autowiring in an Environment variable:

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("classpath:countries.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
```

Then you can get a property by calling env.getProperty("").  You can add that to your model for you main view:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/index","/index.htm","index.html"})
public String indexHtml(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("countries", env.getProperty("whatever")); 
    return "index"; // or whatever the name of your view is
```

Then in your index.jsp you can simply use ${countries} to get the value(s) and do whatever you want with them.  At some point you'll obviously want to parse the whole string into an array.

It is also possible to read the properties file directly into the .jsp file.  Plenty of threads around about that.